# how to get json form remote server via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

this is a json file:

**myjson.php**

```
mylink([
{
"link": "link1",
"url": "http://www.example1.com"
},
{
"link": "link2",
"url": "http://www.example2.com"
},
{
"link": "link3",
"url": "http://www.example3.com"
}
])
```

And I try call it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "json/physician.php",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        json = $.parseJSON(data)
        alert(json.mylink.link[0]);
    }
});
```

but it do not work.(do not return any alert.)
what's my wrong?

Comment: FYI if you change `datatype` to `json` (or remove it completely and let jQuery auto-detect the response type) you can remove the call to `$.parseJSON` as jQuery will do it for you.

Comment: myjson.php appears to be returning JSONP, not JSON.

Comment: your json is not currect formatted..

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid. Valid format for what you're trying to do will be:

```
{         //json
 "myLink": { //.mylink
    "link": [   //.link
        {         //[0]
            "link": "link1",
            "url": "http://www.example1.com"
        },
        {
            "link": "link2",
            "url": "http://www.example2.com"
        },
        {
            "link": "link3",
            "url": "http://www.example3.com"
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

You can validate JSON using tools like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)

Not sure why the file is a `.php` file, you can use [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method to retrieve json data  which will automatically parse the response for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://app.zencoder.com/api/v2/jobs/1234/progress.js?api_key=asdf1234',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
    // write your code 

    }
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain the answer a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are creating a complex json array , also your json is not a valid json array,while you are creating your json array you can check the valid json in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

In simple form here is JSON array in javascript and how to retrieve value
`var mylink=[
    {
        "link": "link1",
        "url": "http://www.example1.com"
    },
    {
        "link": "link2",
        "url": "http://www.example2.com"
    },
    {
        "link": "link3",
        "url": "http://www.example3.com"
    }
];`

after that you can get value from any index of array :-

```
alert(mylink[0].link);
alert(mylink[0].url);
```